# Can I use software from RPM Fusion installed on my laptop for free with no cost and without any risks of lawsuits or other penalties?

Tags: fedora, free-software

Can I use software from rpmfusion installed on my laptop (Fedora installed on it) for free with no cost and without any risks of lawsuits or other penalties?

I tried to read FAQ on RPMFusion.org, but cannot understood fully. So I can use all this software on my laptop even if I work on my laptop for commercial development in java, python and JS? Does software from rpmfusion have any restrictions to free usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two kinds of rpmfusion repositories, free and nonfree. The software from the free repositories are fully opensource. Think of free as in free speech. It is a matter of liberty, not cost. You have the right to use it however you wish without any legal risks, even for commercial development. You are even allowed to modify and redistribute this software. However, some countries do impose restrictions on this kind of software,  which you need to be mindful of. Software from the nonfree repositories however, are only free for use; they are generally closed source and patented or copyright protected. These generally include drivers etc. Modified redistribution of this software could land you in legal turmoil. Personal usage is allowed, and it is in no way illegal. They are published under a nonfree license, but are free of cost. There is no pirated software in any of these repositories if you are worried about that.

With regard to software development, there are certain proprietary IDEs and similar software that may have conditions preventing the user from using them for commercial purposes. You will need to refer to the product's EULA for this. It depends on the specific product. But there are always many fully free and opensource alternatives.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Dont't understand fully only one moment. Can I use with no cost packages from rpmfusion-free and rpmfusion-nonfree on my work in office without any risks of lawsuits or other penalties? I don't plan to use code from this apps or sold them or redistribute etc, only for working process (when I work on tasks from the boss) on office and and at home.

Comment: Unless the products you use have something preventing you from doing so in their end user license agreements, there should be no issues whatsoever. But very few products have such clauses, so don't worry too much about legal ramifications